# How can I effectively edit jupyter notebook's javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

So notebook's js files are all stored in `python_packages_folder/notebook/static/notebook/js` however when I edit them, no change happens and checking the loaded js files on the browser I find them look like as if they were not edited. Why does this happen?

Comment: Cached version of files is provided?

Comment: The js source files are combined and minified into a `.min.js` file for performance. So editing the source files will only affect it once you rebuild that. I think you need to do that from source (i.e. the git repo or an sdist), as it's not possible in an installed copy of the notebook.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasK I edited the .min.js file and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I want to temporarily test some use cases. I hacked it by doing the following:

```
cd python_packages_folder/notebook/static/notebook/js
mv main.min.js main.min.js.bak
cp main.js min.min.js
```

Then you restart your jupyter and open one notebook you will see all the original (not-minified) javascript files. They all come with an `?v=timestamp` suffix, indicating they will be reloaded when you modify them.